# FOREACH with specific KEYs from an array

Tags: php, foreach

i have a list of variables:

```
<?php
$var[1] = "do not show";
$var[2] = "show this #1";
$var[3] = "do not show";
$var[4] = "do not show";
$var[5] = "show this #2";
?>
```

Now i want to use `foreach` to loop `$var[2]` and `$var[5]` only.

I tried to:

```
<?php
foreach(in_array($var,array(2,5)) AS $key => $val){
// condition...
// i don't want filter the data in here...
}
?>
```

but no-luck.

Is it possible to filter the key without having to do it under conditions ?, thanks.

Comment: What is special about index 2 and 5? How do you define it programmatically? is it literally the 2nd and 5th key regardless of condition? You're going to have to use conditions without knowing more information.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php can be used with the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` if you wanted to say only keep values when the key is 2 or 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply test within the loop:

```
<?php
foreach($var as $key=>$val) {
    if ( !in_array($key, [2,5])) { continue; }
    // ... do stuff
}
```

To do what you want is going to be... ugly:

```
<?php
foreach(array_intersect_key($var, ['2'=>'','5'=>'']) as $key=>$val) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Alhamdulillah, thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for a few hours back.